# IE9 Error 80020102, using vbscript Preserve keyword with doctype strict

Tags: javascript, arrays, vbscript, internet-explorer-9

I'm using IE9 beta with the test code below and i encounter an 80020102 error when vbscript tries to append to the array. If I run this in quirks mode it seems to work.

Not knowing if this is an MS issue or something improper I'm doing, I've submitted it to IE9s bug depot. Does anyone have a suggestion on a work around?

I'd post the full html, but it always looks malformed in the preview.

```
-- VBscript part ---    
Function getBlankArray() 
   getBlankArray = Array() 
End Function

Function appendArray(arr, val) 
   redim preserve arr(ubound(arr) + 1) 
   arr(ubound(arr)) = val 
   appendArray = arr 
End Function

-- javascript part --- 
function test()
{
    var contextKeysArray = getBlankArray();
        var jscontextKeysArray = new Array();
    for(var x=0; x < 10; x++)
    {

        jscontextKeysArray[x] = x;

    }

    for(i = 0; i < jscontextKeysArray.length; i++)
    {
            contextKeysArray = (appendArray(contextKeysArray, jscontextKeysArray[i]));
    }

}
```

Comment: Have a read over http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting issues.

Comment: Why are you mixing JS and VBScript code ??? Stick to JS code is IMHO better. In JS, you can call the Array.push(val) method instead of this ugly VBScript appendArray(arr, val) function.

Comment: no error in IE8 in strict mode so indeed an IE9 matter
i agree with Cédric, both languages have their merits but in arrays Javascript surely is better

Answer (score 1):

just try to add this line on top of page if you using html page.

```
<! DOCTYPE html >
```

Comment: A bit late to the party with this answer -- the question is asking about IE9 beta, which is some time in the past. From the question, he also seems to well aware of quirks mode and how to trigger it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using compatibility mode?

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=7; IE=5" >
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I also agree with the comments that if you can get away from the vbscript and use a javascript-only solution you will be better off.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code cleaned up from VBScript:

```
function test() {
    var contextKeysArray = [], jscontextKeysArray = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        jscontextKeysArray[x] = x;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < jscontextKeysArray.length; i++) {
        contextKeysArray.push(jscontextKeysArray[i]);
    }
}
```